# RDD JoinWithCassandraTable Join Columns

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

RDD1.joinWithCassandraTable("keyspace", "Tableabc", SomeColumns("lines"), SomeColumns("col1", "col2", "col3"))

Above is the syntax to join RDD1 with a table in Cassandra. where col1,col2, col3 are the columns used to join with RDD1

I have a requirement as below.
Tableabc has a column with name "lines" which is of datatype "list". 
This lines column has 4 columns like below.

lines:{cola: 22,colb: hello,colc: sri,cold: 123}

Basically its a json object.

Now if you see my syntax above i used SomeColumns("lines"). I am able get the output as a RDD like below.

(RDD1columns,CassandraRow{lines: [{cola: 22,colb: hello,colc: sri,cold:123}]})

But what i need is i just want to select only "cola", i dont need all columns from the lines.

Can anyone please help me on the same.

Comment: I tried to use something like RDD1.joinWithCassandraTable("keyspace", "Tableabc", SomeColumns("lines.cola"), SomeColumns("col1", "col2", "col3"))

Comment: I get a error message like lines.cola doesnot exist.

Comment: After getting the json you could use map and parse the json to get cola

Answer (score 0):

JoinWithCassandraTable invokes a direct join on the database and can only be used when joining on Partition Keys. If you would like to join on a portion of the partition key you will need to do a full scan.

This means is it impossible to do a JWCT on any collection columns.

Also how is `lines` a List when it has key:value pairs?

If you only want the "cola" value from lines you can just do a map

```
RDD1.joinWithCassandraTable().map(_._2.get[Map[String, AnyRef]](lines).get("cola"))
```